# Extract text in Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, I want to extract array from a string.
The string is

```
var str = "abc (24 314 83 383)(-256)sa 0 (24 314) 1"
```

I want priority to be the text in parentheses then other text separated by white space. So for the above example, the result should to be:

```
result[0] = "abc"
result[1] = "24 314 83 383"
result[2] = "-256"
result[3] = "sa"
result[4] = "0"
result[5] = "24 314"
result[6] = "1"
```

I tried

```
var pattern = /(.*?)[\s|\)]/g;
result = str.match(pattern);
```

but the result was: `abc ,(24 ,314 ,83 ,383),(-256),sa ,0 ,(24 ,314),`

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Where has the `0` in the original string gone?

Comment: You can use: /(?!\()[\w -]+(?=\))|[\w-]+/g That will do it in one shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a regex object and `exec`, which is safer than filtering out parenthesis with something like `str.match(/\w+|\((.*?)\)/g).map(e => e.replace(/^\(|\)$/g, ""))`:

```js
var str = "abc (24 314 83 383)(-256)sa 0 (24 314) 1";
var reg = /\w+|\((.*?)\)/g;
var match;
var res = [];

while (match = reg.exec(str)) {
  res.push(match[1] || match[0]);
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
let str = "abc (24 314 83 383)(-256)sa 0 (24 314) 1";
let replaced = str.replace(/(\s*\(|\))/g, '<REP>');
let arrFromStr = replaced.split('<REP>').filter(w => w.length != 0);
```

Variable "replaced" replaces all 1) 0 or more spaces + "(", and 2) all ")" symbols to "" string.
arrFromStr creates an array from string and split it with "". Then we check is the element of array empty, or not.

Comment: Some explanation of what this is doing (explaining *why* it works) would be helpful.

Comment: Is this a good explanation?) Maybe I said something wrong. My English is not perfect yet.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
var str = "abc (24 314 83 383)(-256)sa 0 (24 314) 1"
var pattern = /\((.*?)\)|\s?(\S+)\s?/g;
var result = str.match(pattern).map(v => v.trim().replace(/^\(|\)$/g, ''));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, it had a trailing space in the array items. I accepted another solution since it was do the work perfectly

Comment: @MostafaFouda, you can add `.trim()`, see the updated answer.